# Ember bindAttr to classname on page render

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember template which contains two buttons and a div. The buttons toggle a controller value to `true` and `false`. I'm using the `bindAttr` helper to set a class on the currently toggled button and on the div.

This works fine once I have clicked a button, but the class names are not setup correctly on initial page render. If I print the `toggled` property into the template it shows as the correct value, it just doesn't seem to affect the class name bindings until it changes.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```html
<div {{bindAttr class="toggled:is-toggled"}}></div>
<button {{action toggleOn}} {{bindAttr class="isToggled:is-active"}}>Toggle on</button>
<button {{action toggleOff}} {{bindAttr class="notToggled:is-active"}}>Toggle off</button>
```

```js
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  toggled: fasle,

  isToggled: function() {
    return this.get('toggled');
  }.property('toggled'),

  notToggled: function() {
    return !this.get('toggled');
  }.property('toggled'),

  actions: {
    toggleOn: function() {
      this.set('toggled', true);
    },

    toggleOff: function() {
      this.set('toggled', false);
    }

  }
});
```

I expect this is something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. Can anyone help? Here's a jsbin showing the same code http://jsbin.com/esURuWE/8/edit.

Comment: Quick update, it seems that if I set the initial value inside an Ember.run.next block it works:   init: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
      self.set('toggled', false);
    });
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
toggled: fasle,
```

shouldn't it be

```
toggled: false,
```

A working Jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/epodAwU/1/edit)

Also You need not to have properties for returning truthy or falsy value of the `toggled` property, you can directly use the `toggled` property as the binded attribute

```
<button {{action toggleOn}} {{bind-attr class="toggled:is-active"}}>Toggle on</button>
<button {{action toggleOff}} {{bind-attr class="toggled::is-active"}}>Toggle off</button>
```

Note the `toggled::is-active`, here `is-active` is set when `toggled` is false

And also the camelCased version of `bindAttr` is deprecated, use `bind-attr` instead.

Hope these helps